# Magento 2 : how to add product images jpg or png using rest api

Tags: magento2, product-images, rest-api

Any options to add product jpg or png using rest api in magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

try with additional POST with the route :

`http://testsite.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/ABC-SKU/media`

the template JSON would be something like:

```
{
    "entry": {
        "media_type": "image",
        "label": "Test image",
        "position": 1,
        "disabled": false,
        "types": [
            "image",
            "small_image",
            "thumbnail"
        ],
        "content": {
            "base64EncodedData": YOU_NEED_YOUR_IMAGE_BASE64_ENCODED,
            "type": "image/png",
            "name": "testimage.png"
        }
    }
}
```

I hope its work for you.